# unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'dict' and 'unicode'

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python python requests to connect an api.
Sample connection for api is

```
curl -H"Authorization:Bearer <token>"-H"Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"filter" :{}}'https://sandbox-api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/search
```

My code is:

```
import requests

class FlipkartAPI:
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token

    def search_orders(self):
        headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer %s',
                'Content-Type':'application/json'} % self.token
        url = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/search"
        return requests.get(url, params = headers)
```

The variable token is of type unicode.

 What is wrong with my code?

EDIT:
My code to fetch orders:

```
from auth import Authentication
from api import FlipkartAPI

app_id = 'app id'
app_secret = 'app secret'

auth = Authentication(app_id, app_secret)
get_token = auth.get_access_token()
token_str = get_token.json()
token = token_str['access_token']

fk = FlipkartAPI(token)
orders = fk.search_orders()
print orders
```

I can generate a token means my app id and app secret are correct And i am authorized to get access.
Also link to api documentation:

[Flipkart Documentation](https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/FMSAPI.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the `%` operation to the *string with the format placeholder*, not the dictionary:

```
headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer %s' % self.token,
           'Content-Type':'application/json'}
```

You are also using the wrong keyword argument, the wrong HTTP method, and are not setting a JSON payload.

- use `headers`, not `params`
- use POST, the `curl` `-d` switch indicates that a POST request is made, not a GET
- you forgot to provide a JSON body with a `filter`

The correct translation of the `curl` command then is:

```
headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer %s',
        'Content-Type':'application/json'} % self.token
url = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/search"
filter = {'filter': {}}

return requests.post(url, json=filter, headers=headers)
```

The `json` parameter was added to `requests` version 2.4.2; if you have an older version you'll need to encode the JSON body yourself:

```
import json

# ...

return requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(filter), headers=headers)
```

Comment: The above code is giving me this error   ---   TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json'

Comment: @ManishGupta: then you have an older `requests` version. Use `data=json.dumps(filter)` in that case, instead of the `json` keyword argument.

Comment: Did you mean like this : requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(filter), headers=headers) .It says global name json is not defined

Comment: @ManishGupta: yes, you need to import the `json` module for that. I've updated my answer with more information.

Comment: Now it gives response 404

Comment: @ManishGupta: I note that your `curl` command uses a *different* URL; `https://sandbox-api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/search` vs. `https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/search`. Is that deliberate? What does the flipkart.net API documentation state you should use?

Comment: actually the url in curl command is for sandbox. the url i m using is for production.

Comment: @ManishGupta: sure, but is it the *correct* URL? What does their documentation say?

Comment: Plz check question edit. yes the url is correct and i have added a link to documentation.

Comment: @ManishGupta: the documentation suggests that an error response includes a body; what does the response `.text` attribute or `.json()` method produce in that case?

Comment: the response is         {"errors":[{"type":null,"code":"CLIENT_ERROR","message":"Client response status: 404","params":null}]}

Comment: Right, that's not very helpful. I'm out of options; the URL looks correct according to the documentation. I suggest you contact their support.

Comment: I got the problem. I needed to pass atleast 1 filter param. And now it worked.

Comment: Ah, then their documentation example (the one you copied into your question) is wrong and unhelpful, as that uses an empty filter, and they state all filters are optional.